# Is Ogulsabyr a male or female name?

Tags: other-languages, ономастика

I received an email from someone called *Ogulsabyr*, and I’m not sure whether to use Mr. or Ms. in my reply. That is, I was wondering whether Ogulsabyr is a male or female name. I’ve tried search engines, but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: This is not exactly RL&U question, as it is not a Russian name, but it is, possibly, the best place for this on SE, so I’ll have an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @theUg, Please ignore my ignorance on this! Thank you... I look forward to know.

Comment: And this is not a stupid question. I, for one, did not know this, and would not know how to address this person had I not also known their last name (if it was patterned as I described in my answer). I shall edit your question accordingly. :)

Comment: Many thanks, theUg!!!!! Your information is very helpful :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [Turkmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkmenistan) name, and it is a girl’s name. To add some general knowledge so one could identify those names in the future, here is the quote from the ethnography [*Tradition and Society in Turkmenistan: Gender, Oral Culture and Song*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZwUSitzGojkC&lpg=PP1&hl=ru&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Carole Blackwell (2001, Richmond, Surrey, UK, [p. 62](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZwUSitzGojkC&lpg=PA62&ots=CHvcp_c3my&dq=meaning%20of%20turkmen%20names%20ogulsabyr&hl=ru&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> In families with several daughters, it is not uncommon for the name of every girl to began with *Ogul*, the Turkmen word for son; common examples are Ogulsabyr (let us wait patiently for a son), Oguldursun and Oguldurndy (may a son be born who will stay), and Ogulgerek (we need a son).

Also, as a general rule, many people form former Soviet republics adopted for their family names the convention from Russian tradition, that is, the pattern to end the last name with *-ov* (*-ow*) for males and *-ova* (*-owa*) for women (grammatical gender identification). You can see many of this type of last names amongst, say, respective Olympic athletes.